# Which monitor should I buy for my macbook air M1 and a possible Minisforum UM560?

Tags: monitors, mini-pc, macbook

Currently, I have a MacBook Air M1 (2020) running MacOS 13.3.1. I am planning to buy a [Minisforum UM560](https://store.minisforum.com/collections/amd-%C2%AE-ryzen-%C2%AE/products/um560?variant=43016070529269) to run a Linux environment.

Also, I am planning to buy a *monitor*. I would like to have a *big* monitor (more than 27'') compatible with **both computers** (the mac and the Minisforum).

I do *not* care about gaming or design/video editing/photoshop. I use the computer for "productivity" (I am a software engineer).

Which monitor would you recommend? Which specs should I avoid?